# Why can't scp resolve the second hostname?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am trying to copy from one remote-machine to another using my local machine.
Both remotes are added in the local `~/.ssh/config` as follows:

```
Host source
        Hostname <public-ip>
        IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/source-key-file
        User source_me
        ServerAliveInterval 60
        Compression yes
        ForwardX11 yes
Host destiny
        Hostname <different-public-ip>
        IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/destiny-key-file
        User destiny_me
        ServerAliveInterval 60
        Compression yes
        ForwardX11 yes
```

The following work without any problems:

```
scp source:~/file .
scp destiny:~/another_file .
```

as well as

```
scp file source:~
scp file destiny:~
```

Anyway, trying to copy from one to another by using

```
scp source:~/file destiny:~
```

throws an error saying:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname destiny: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

Why doesn't this work as I expected it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For remote-to-remote copies, traditionally the `scp` tool has initiated the connection *directly from the source host* – that is, it's not your local machine that would resolve `destiny`, it's actually the `source` machine that needs to know about it.

(Like many other quirks in ssh/scp, this was meant to mirror the behavior of [the old `rcp` tool](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rcp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+4.1.3&arch=default&format=html#:%7E:text=rcp%20%20requires%20%20that%20the%20source%20host%20have%09permission%20to%20execute%20commands%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20on%20the%20remote%20host%20when%20doing%20third%2Dparty%20copies.).)

You'll need to specify the `-3` option to force copying through the local machine:

```
scp -3 source:~/file destiny:
```

Note that this has already been changed in OpenSSH v8.7, which [made `-3` the default](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7)… so really it's because you're using an outdated version of OpenSSH.